# Mongoose ref problems

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

So here is my sample, we have 2 models both of them are linked to each other. But these sample will only work if I use string values for ref(e.g. ref: "Cat/Dog"). But when I try to use them in that way, it's instantly gives me these error. Can someone explain where is the problem or it's just some king of bug?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUnfU.png)

Comment: I don't think DBRef support linkage other than [_id field](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#format) of linked document.

Comment: Please edit to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.